# Align and split subequations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, subequations, alignat

I would like to ask for some help with aligning `subequations`. Note that we have two `subequations` that need to be split due to its size. Thus, my code is:

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{alignat}{4}
\begin{aligned}
& B_{1(t)} &= -L_{x_{1(t)0}} & - S_{u1(t)0}^{-1} \left( L_{s_{u1(t)0}} - Y_{u1(t)0} \, L_{\lambda_{u1(t)0}} \right) \\
                    & &      & - S_{l1(t)0}^{-1} \left( L_{s_{l1(t)0}} + Y_{l1(t)0} \, L_{\lambda_{l1(t)0}} \right), 
                             B_{1(t)} \in \mathscr{R}^p ;
\end{aligned}   
\\
\begin{aligned}
& B_{2(t)} &= -L_{x_{2(t)0}} & - S_{u2(t)0}^{-1} \left( L_{s_{u2(t)0}} - Y_{u2(t)0} \, L_{\lambda_{u2(t)0}} \right) \\
                    & &      & - S_{l2(t)0}^{-1} \left( L_{s_{l2(t)0}} + Y_{l2(t)0} \, L_{\lambda_{l2(t)0}} \right), 
                             B_{2(t)} \in \mathscr{R}^q ;
\end{aligned}
\\
\begin{aligned}
A_{(n,t)} & = A_{(t,n)}^T = \left[ \, M_t \, | \, 0 \, \right]_{p \times (p+q+3n)}, A_{(n,t)} \in \mathscr{R}^{p \times (p+q+3n)};
\end{aligned}
\\
\begin{aligned}
A_{(n,n)} & = Y_{n0}^{-1} \, S_{n0} \, I, A_{(n,n)} \in \mathscr{R}^{p \times p};
\end{aligned}
\\
\begin{aligned}
b_n       & = L_{\lambda_{n0}} - Y_{n0}^{-1} L_{s_{n0}}, b_n \in \mathscr{R}^p;
\end{aligned}
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}
```

The result is:

[image]

The desired output is something similar to the following, by aligning to the '=':

[image]

Any ideas how to achieve the desired output?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  please extend your example so that it's compilable (with `\documentclass` and `\begin{document} ... \end{document}`) so we can cut and paste to compile.  i think an outer `align` with nested `alignedat'  groups is what's mostly wanted.  at least it would get rid of the too-wide spaces before the = signs in (6.9h) and (6.9i), but it wouldn't align everything to the left of the first = signs at the left.  that needs more work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd *suggest* not being too concerned about the vertical placement of the split equation numbering, and just set them in line with the last segment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    B_{1(t)}  &= -L_{x_{1(t)0}} - S_{u1(t)0}^{-1} \bigl( L_{s_{u1(t)0}} - Y_{u1(t)0} \, L_{\lambda_{u1(t)0}} \bigr) \nonumber \\
              &\hphantom{{}= -L_{x_{1(t)0}}} - S_{l1(t)0}^{-1} \bigl( L_{s_{l1(t)0}} + Y_{l1(t)0} \, L_{\lambda_{l1(t)0}} \bigr), B_{1(t)} \in \mathscr{R}^p ; \\
    B_{2(t)}  &= -L_{x_{2(t)0}} - S_{u2(t)0}^{-1} \bigl( L_{s_{u2(t)0}} - Y_{u2(t)0} \, L_{\lambda_{u2(t)0}} \bigr) \nonumber \\
              &\hphantom{{}= -L_{x_{2(t)0}}} - S_{l2(t)0}^{-1} \bigl( L_{s_{l2(t)0}} + Y_{l2(t)0} \, L_{\lambda_{l2(t)0}} \bigr), B_{2(t)} \in \mathscr{R}^q ; \\
    A_{(n,t)} &= A_{(t,n)}^T = \bigl[ \, M_t \, | \, 0 \, \bigr]_{p \times (p+q+3n)}, A_{(n,t)} \in \mathscr{R}^{p \times (p+q+3n)}; \\
    A_{(n,n)} &= Y_{n0}^{-1} \, S_{n0} \, I, A_{(n,n)} \in \mathscr{R}^{p \times p}; \\
    b_n       &= L_{\lambda_{n0}} - Y_{n0}^{-1} L_{s_{n0}}, b_n \in \mathscr{R}^p;
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

I've used `align` which is typically used only with one alignment along the relation. In order to achieve the second alignment for the split equations, we insert an `\hphantom`.

The above solution does align the left-hand side of the `align` to the *right*, which differs from your example/expected output. However, this seems more standard. That could be changed though.

Answer (score 0):

How about this way?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
  \begin{alignat}{2}
    B_{1(t)} &= \!\mathrlap{\begin{alignedat}[t]{2}-L_{x_{1(t)0}} & - S_{u1(t)0}⁻¹ \left( L_{s_{u1(t)0}} - Y_{u1(t)0} \, L_{\lambda_{u1(t)0}} \right) \\
              & - S_{l1(t)0}⁻¹ \left( L_{s_{l1(t)0}} + Y_{l1(t)0} \, L_{\lambda_{l1(t)0}} \right), & \enspace B_{1(t)} & ∈ \mathscr{R}^p ; \end{alignedat}} \\[1ex]
    B_{2(t)} &= \!\mathrlap{\begin{alignedat}[t]{2}-L_{x_{2(t)0}} & - S_{u2(t)0}⁻¹ \left( L_{s_{u2(t)0}} - Y_{u2(t)0} \, L_{\lambda_{u2(t)0}} \right) \\
              & - S_{l2(t)0}⁻¹ \left( L_{s_{l2(t)0}} + Y_{l2(t)0} \, L_{\lambda_{l2(t)0}} \right), & \enspace B_{2(t)} & ∈ \mathscr{R}^q ; \end{alignedat}} \\[1ex]
    A_{(n,t)} & = A_{(t,n)}^T = \left[ \, M_t \, | \, 0 \, \right]_{p × (p+q+3n)}, & \qquad A_{(n,t)} & ∈ \mathscr{R}^{p × (p+q+3n)};
    \\[1ex]
    A_{(n,n)} & = Y_{n0}⁻¹ \, S_{n0} \, I, & A_{(n,n)} & ∈ \mathscr{R}^{p × p};
    \\[1ex]
    b_n & = L_{\lambda_{n0}} - Y_{n0}⁻¹ L_{s_{n0}}, & b_n & ∈ \mathscr{R}^p;
  \end{alignat}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]